# Last 10 completed week's data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming i want to extract last 10 completed weeks' data (ie week 42 - week 52 from table below as week 53 and 0 are not completed 7 days) from a table and do some calculation
How can i do it with MySQL?

A couple of extra considerations:

1. table may contain multiple years' data ie multiple wk numbers 2019 week 51 and 2020 week 51
2. how to deal with not consecutive week number ie week 44 to next year week 2

```
dt          wk
2020-12-14  51
2020-12-15  51
2020-12-16  51
2020-12-17  51
2020-12-18  51
2020-12-19  51
2020-12-20  51
2020-12-21  52
2020-12-22  52
2020-12-23  52
2020-12-24  52
2020-12-25  52
2020-12-26  52
2020-12-27  52
2020-12-28  53
2020-12-29  53
2020-12-30  53
2020-12-31  53
2021-01-01  0
```

Comment: *last 10 completed weeks' data (ie week 42 - week 52* This is last 11 weeks, not 10 :)

Comment: Your example is rather confusing.  I don't see how weeks could be numbered with both `0` and `53`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that all seven days are in a week using window functions.  Assuming your weeks restart at each year:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by year(dt) desc, wk desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by wk, year(dt)) as wk_cnt
            from t
           ) t
      where wk_cnt = 7
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, should be: order by year(dt) desc